# Emulating the GLSL flat qualifier in GLSL 120

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to emulate flat shading in a GLSL shader. Usually I would do that by passing the normal with a `flat` qualifier to prevent interpolation in the fragment shader.
However, `flat` is not available on GLSL 120.

How can I emulate it without duplicating the vertex data? (This is *not* premature optimization, rather post-mortem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot exactly emulate `flat` without direct hardware support (presumably as indicated by supporting GLSL 1.30+). Prior versions only offer all-or-nothing: either all attributes are interpolated or none are. That's what [`glShadeModel`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glShadeModel.xml) does.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the same normal for each vertex of a triangle.

Or see if `glShadeModel(GL_FLAT)` affects the `gl_Normal` built-in attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry: I forgot to mention a requirement in the question. Fixed.

Comment: That's a rather important requirement :)

Comment: `glShadeModel` affects all (at least most) built-in attributes. But this will give me wrong normals, which has a large impact if the angle between adjacent triangles is large.